# How do I call this function with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get the code to run but nothing happens as Im not sure if I have to call the function or does it run automatically.

When using the window.onload method I would give the function a name < init > and it would run.
Calling it with jquery im un sure if I should have a function name or not?

how should I get the code to run please.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {
    var xhr = false;
    var xPos, yPos;

    function () {
        var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

        for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
            allLinks[i].onmouseover = showPreview;
        }

    } //end function
    function showPreview(evt) {
        if (evt) {
            var url = evt.target;
        } else {
            evt = window.event;
            var url = evt.srcElement;
        }
        xPos = evt.clientX;
        yPos = evt.clientY;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        }

        if (xhr) {
            xhr.onreadystatechange = showContents;
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.send(null);
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, but I couldn't create an XMLHttpRequest");
        }
        return false;
    }

    function showContents() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                var outMsg = xhr.responseText;
            } else {
                var outMsg = "There was a problem with the request " + xhr.status;
            }
            var prevWin = document.getElementById('previewWin');
            prevWin.innerHTML = outMsg;
            prevWin.style.top = parseInt(yPos) + 2 + "px";
            prevWin.style.left = parseInt(xPos) + 2 + "px";
            prevWin.style.visibility = "visible";

            preview.onmouseout = function () {
                document.getElementById('preview').style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Give me the number and.. I'll call him! (It's not exactly clear from your Q nor the code what you want. Please be more specific.)

Comment: if i was to add a function name at the top of my code instead of the $(document).ready ... lets say function init() and call the function with window.onload init(); it would run the whole of the code.

Comment: `function () {` isn't valid JavaScript.  You can't make an un-named function like that.

Comment: I have just called it init .. the function () {  and called it at the bottom of the script before the close .ready function. It works  know and I know how to call it thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have declared the functions. There is no where you are calling the functions so that it executes.

You won't be able to call this functions from outside as they are declared inside the document.ready function. Do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showcontent(){
    };
    showcontent();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## jQuery === JavaScript

So calling a function in jQuery is exact the same as calling a function in JavaScript.

The only thing jQuery does is create easy-to-use methods and functions to speed up your JavaScript development. For example, the `window.onload` event is replaced by a `$(document).ready()` event.

Comment: so where do i call the function?? in the html ?? at the bottom of the script?? where

Comment: @StudentRik the `$(document).ready()` function is the normal `init()` function. What you place in the init function with 'normal' JS you place it in the ready function with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, inline JavaScript:

```
<script>...yourcode...</script>
```

Or linked javascript in an external file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

usually linked files are in the head tags, inline scripts would be at the bottom.

If you are unsing jQuery you also need to include this library http://jquery.com

```
function () {
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
        allLinks[i].onmouseover = showPreview;
    }

} //end function
```

Should really be:

```
function () {
    var allLinks = $("a");

    allLinks.on("mouseover", showPreview);

} //end function
```

Comment: *"usually linked files are in the head tags, inline scripts would be at the bottom."* I suggest place it all on the bottom. Also on both tags the `type` attribute isn't required.

Comment: personal preference really, most places advise placing at the bottom, but from expierence I would at least place the jQuery lib at the top of the document and then use defered loading of JS files